# Python How to open an URL and get source code at the same time?

Tags: python

What I had try are as following:

1)

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
```

In this way, I can't open the url in browser.

2)

```
webbrowser.open(url)
```

In this way, I can't get source code of the url.

So, how can I open an URL and get source code at the same time?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Either your browser or Python opens the URL. You can't do both in one step.

Comment: `ctrl + u` ? :p

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at BeautifulSoup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

You can request a website and then read the HTML source code from it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(YourURL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.prettify()
```

If you want to read JavaScript, look into Headless Browsers.